# Updating other players screen Django

Tags: python, django, tornado

I am developing a small game with four members for a board. When a player moves something, that move has to updated in remaining players screen(their webpage). I ended up tornado, but I can't find any examples for my case.

I need to display the move to all players when a move was saved in DB. Polling DB continuously after x seconds may miss some moves. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use websockets instead. Here's the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html) with a simple example.